# Elasticsearch Nested output buckets’ aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Here is my doc type: vehicles is a nested type.

document1 -

```
{
  "customerAge": 30,
  "vehicles": [
    {
      "brand": "Altima",
      "year": 2005
    },
    {
      "brand": "Corolla",
      "year": 2006
    },
    {
      "brand": "Camry",
      "year": 2005
    }
  ]
}
```

document2 -

```
{
  "customerAge": 50,
  "vehicles": [
    {
      "brand": "Altima",
      "year": 2009
    },
    {
      "brand": "Corolla",
      "year": 2010
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to create buckets of vehicle brand and calculate the averages of customer age. So in this example "Altima" bucket's average customer age will be 40.

I tried this query and the averages are null.

Could someone please help what am I doing incorrectly?

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "nestedtop": {
         "nested": {
            "path": "vehicles"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "3cc601456260531278": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "vehicles.brand"
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "expfilter_yromb0g90dmjx20529": {
                     "filter": {
                        "match_all": {}
                     },
                     "aggs": {
                        "yromb0g90dmjx20529": {
                           "min": {
                              "field": "customerAge"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested aggregation can access only the fields within the nested document. It can’t see fields in the root document or in a different nested document. However, we can step out of the nested scope back into the parent with a [reverse_nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-aggregation.html#reverse-nested-aggregation).

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "nestedtop": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "vehicles"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "by_name": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "vehicles.brand"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "age_reverse": {
                            "reverse_nested": {},
                            "aggs": {
                                "avg_age": {
                                    "avg": {
                                        "field": "customerAge"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is reverse_nested expensive operation?

Comment: I dont think it is. It just changes the nested scope to parent doc